# String Override limited to certain pages?

Tags: 7, string-overrides

I'm using the [Fivestar](http://drupal.org/project/fivestar) module on different areas of the site. It displays "x votes" below the rating widget.

On some areas on the site it would like to change "votes" to "reviews". How could I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'votes' text seems to be hard-coded into the `theme_fivestar_summary()` function (around line 264 of 'includes/fivestar.theme.inc'). It is run through `format_plural()` (so will eventually make itself available to string overrides), but I don't know of a way of defining complex conditions/contexts for string overrides.

The only (easy) way I can see to solve this is to re-implement that theme function in your own theme, copying the full function code from `theme_fivestar_summary()` to `MYTHEME_fivestar_summary()`, and introducing a contextual condition to alter the specific text that you want to change.

You'd be basically looking at changing these lines:

```
if (isset($votes) && !(isset($user_rating) || isset($average_rating))) {
  $output .= ' <span class="total-votes">'. format_plural($votes, '<span>@count</span> vote', '<span>@count</span> votes') .'</span>';
  $div_class = 'count';
}
elseif (isset($votes)) {
  $output .= ' <span class="total-votes">('. format_plural($votes, '<span>@count</span> vote', '<span>@count</span> votes') .')</span>';
}
```

to:

```
$context = MYTHEME_get_fivestar_context();
if ($context == 'something') {
  $metric = 'review';
}
else if ($context == 'something_else') {
  $metric = 'vote';
}

if (isset($votes) && !(isset($user_rating) || isset($average_rating))) {
  $output .= ' <span class="total-votes">'. format_plural($votes, '<span>@count</span> ' . $metric, '<span>@count</span> ' . $metric . 's') .'</span>';
  $div_class = 'count';
}
elseif (isset($votes)) {
  $output .= ' <span class="total-votes">('. format_plural($votes, '<span>@count</span> ' . $metric, '<span>@count</span> ' . $metric . 's') .')</span>';
}
```

It's not particularly pretty, but I think it's about the most efficient way to do it.